# Last week vs current week

Tags: sql, oracle, difference

We have the fact table with multiple dimensions date, product, customer and measures like revenue, sales...

We would like to calculate the difference between the revenue, sales number between the last week vs this week ( between two dates).

Kindly help to create a sql query that can help to achieve .

Thanks.

Comment: Please show your current query, your DDL and some DML for us to understand clearly the issue you're facing. At it stands, I downvoted this question for "unclearness" but I would cancel it if you added some further information.

Answer (score 0):

```
to_number(to_char(DateField,'WW'))
```

will give you a week number within year. [More...](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php)